# base64 iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, base64

Was a tiny bit bored reading authentication protocols.
Needed to clear the mind and read some base64 encode text.

So I implemented these iterators that will encode or decode base64 text.

Not sure about:

- Interface is there a better way
- Iterator Implementation (its been a while since I did one)
- How easy to make this work with Ranges?

Usage:

```
 int main()
 {
      std::string  data = getBase64Message(); // retrieves a message base 64 encoded.
      std::string  message(make_decode64(std::begin(data)), 
                           make_decode64(std::end(data)));
      std::cout << message << "\n";

      std::copy(make_encode64(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin)),
                make_encode64(std::istream_iterator<char>()),
                std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

 }
```

The basic concept is that they are iterators that are constructed with other iterators. So you can decode any type of container as long as you can get a readable iterator to it (technically the iterator has to be an input iterator).

---

Nobody has submitted a review. So I am adding version 2 the cleaned up (and commented) version to the question. I will leave the original version at the bottom for comparison:

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_BASE_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_BASE_H

namespace ThorsAnvil::Crypto
{

template<typename I>
class Base64DecodeIterator
{
    I       iter    = I{};
    int     bits    = 0;
    int     buffer  = 0;
    public:

    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = char;
    using pointer           = char*;
    using reference         = char&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    Base64DecodeIterator()  {}
    Base64DecodeIterator(I iter)
        : iter(iter)
    {}

    // Check state of iterator.
    // We are not done until all the bits have been read even if we are at the end iterator.
    bool operator==(Base64DecodeIterator const& rhs) const  {return (iter == rhs.iter) && (bits == 0);}
    bool operator!=(Base64DecodeIterator const& rhs) const  {return !(*this == rhs);}

    // Increment Simply remove bits.
    // Note: The interface for input iterator required a * before each ++ operation.
    //       So we don't need to do any work on the ++ operator but do it all in the * operator
    Base64DecodeIterator& operator++()      {bits -= 8;return *this;}
    Base64DecodeIterator operator++(int)    {Base64DecodeIterator  result(this);++(*this);return result;}

    char operator*()
    {
        // If nothing in the buffer than fill it up.
        if (bits == 0)
        {
            static constexpr char convert[]
                    = "\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F"    //   0 - 15 00 - 0F
                      "\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F"    //  16 - 31 10 - 1F
                      "\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x3E\x8F\x8F\x8F\x3F"    //  32 - 47 20 - 2F + /
                      "\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3A\x3B\x3C\x3D\x8F\x8F\x8F\x40\x8F\x8F"    //  48 - 63 30 - 3F 0-9
                      "\x8F\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x0E"    //  64 - 79 40 - 4F A-O
                      "\x0F\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F"    //  80 - 95 50 - 5F P-Z
                      "\x8F\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28"    //  96 -111 60 - 6F a-o
                      "\x29\x2A\x2B\x2C\x2D\x2E\x2F\x30\x31\x32\x33\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F\x8F";   // 112 -127 70 - 7F p-z

            int extra = 0;
            // Base64 input is based on the input being 3 input bytes => 4 output bytes.
            // There will always be a multiple of 3 bytes on the input. So read 3 bytes
            // at a time.
            while (bits != 24)
            {
                unsigned char tmp = *iter++;
                unsigned char b64 = convert[tmp & 0x7F];
                if (b64 == 0x8F || tmp > 0x7F)
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("Base64DecodeIterator::operator*: invalid input");
                }
                if (b64 == 0x40)    // We found a padding byte '='
                {
                    extra += 8;
                    b64 = 0;
                }

                buffer = (buffer << 6) | b64;
                bits  = bits + 6;
            }
            // Remove any padding bits we found.
            buffer = buffer >> extra;
            bits -= extra;
        }
        char result = (buffer >> (bits - 8)) & 0xFF;
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename I>
class Base64EncodeIterator
{
    I               iter    = I{};
    mutable int     bits    = 0;
    mutable int     buffer  = 0;
    public:

    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = char;
    using pointer           = char*;
    using reference         = char&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    Base64EncodeIterator() {}
    Base64EncodeIterator(I iter)
        : iter(iter)
    {}
    enum Flags
    {
            EndFlag  = 0x8000,
            FillFlag = 0x4000,
            Data     = 0x3FFF,
    };

    bool operator==(Base64EncodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        // Note: That we have reached the end of the input stream.
        //       That means we can not read more data in the * operator.
        // Note: The input iterator interface requires you to the check␣
        //       the iterator against end before continuing.
        if (iter == rhs.iter)
        {
            buffer = buffer | EndFlag;
        }
        // We are not finished even if we have reached the end iterator
        // if there is still data left to decode in the buffer.
        return (iter == rhs.iter) && (bits == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(Base64EncodeIterator const& rhs) const  {return !(*this == rhs);}

    // Increment the current position.
    Base64EncodeIterator& operator++()      {bits -= 6;return *this;}
    Base64EncodeIterator operator++(int)    {Base64EncodeIterator  result(this);++(*this);return result;}

    char operator*()
    {
        // We convert three 8 bit values int four 6 bit values.
        // But the input can be any size (i.e. it is not padded to length).
        // We must therefore detect then end of stream (see operator ==) and
        // insert the appropriate padding on the output. But this also means
        // we can not simply keep reading from the input as we cant detect
        // the end here.
        //
        // Therefor we only reads 1 byte at a time from the input. We don't
        // need to read a byte every call as we have 2 bits left over from
        // each character read thus every four call to this function will
        // return a byte without a read.
        //
        // Note this means the buffer will only ever have a maximum of 14 bits (0-13)␣
        // of data in it. We re-use bits 14/15 as flags. Bit 15 marks the end
        // Bit 14 indicates that we should return a padding character.

        // Check if we should return a padding character.
        bool fillFlag = buffer & FillFlag;


        if (bits < 6)
        {
            if (buffer & EndFlag)
            {
                // If we have reached the end if the input
                // we simply pad the data with 0 value in the buffer.
                // Note we add the FillFlag here so the next call
                // will be returning a padding character
                buffer = EndFlag | FillFlag | ((buffer << 8) & Data);
            }
            else
            {
                // Normal operation. Read data from the input
                // Add it to the buffer.
                unsigned char tmp = *iter++;
                buffer = ((buffer << 8) | tmp) &  Data;
            }
            bits += 8;
        }

        static constexpr char convert[]
                    = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"    // 00 - 0F
                      "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef"    // 10 - 1F
                      "ghijklmnopqrstuv"    // 20 - 2F
                      "wxyz0123456789+/";   // 30 - 3F
        // Output is either padding or converting the 6 bit value into an encoding.
        char result = fillFlag ? '=' : convert[(buffer >> (bits - 6)) & 0x3F];

        return result;
    }
};

template<typename I>
Base64DecodeIterator<I> make_decode64(I iter)
{
    return Base64DecodeIterator<I>(iter);
}
template<typename I>
Base64EncodeIterator<I> make_encode64(I iter)
{
    return Base64EncodeIterator<I>(iter);
}

}

#endif
```

---

The original version is below:

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_BASE_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_CRYPTO_BASE_H

namespace ThorsAnvil::Crypto
{

template<typename I>
class Base64DecodeIterator
{
    I       iter;
    int     bits;
    int     value;
    public:

    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = char;
    using pointer           = char*;
    using reference         = char&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    Base64DecodeIterator()
        : iter(I{})
        , bits(0)
        , value(0)
    {}
    Base64DecodeIterator(I iter)
        : iter(iter)
        , bits(0)
        , value(0)
    {}
    bool operator==(Base64DecodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return (iter == rhs.iter) && (bits == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(Base64DecodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    bool operator<(Base64DecodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return iter < rhs.iter || (iter == rhs.iter && bits != 0);
    }
    char operator*()
    {
        if (bits == 0)
        {
            int extra = 0;
            while (bits != 24)
            {
                unsigned char tmp = *iter++;
                unsigned char b64;
                if (tmp >= 'A' && tmp <= 'Z')
                {
                    b64 = tmp - 'A';
                }
                else if (tmp >= 'a' && tmp <= 'z')
                {
                    b64 = tmp - 'a' + 26;
                }
                else if (tmp >= '0' && tmp <= '9')
                {
                    b64 = tmp - '0' + 52;
                }
                else if (tmp == '+')
                {
                    b64 = 63;
                }
                else if (tmp == '/')
                {
                    b64 = 64;
                }
                else if (tmp == '=')
                {
                    b64 = 0;
                    extra   += 8;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("Bad Input");
                }

                value = (value << 6) | b64;
                bits  = bits + 6;
            }
            value = value >> extra;
            bits -= extra;
        }
        char result = (value >> (bits - 8)) & 0xFF;
        return result;
    }
    Base64DecodeIterator& operator++()
    {
        bits -= 8;
        return *this;
    }
    Base64DecodeIterator operator++(int)
    {
        Base64DecodeIterator  result(this);
        bits -= 8;
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename I>
class Base64EncodeIterator
{
    I       iter;
    mutable int     bits;
    mutable int     value;
    public:

    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = char;
    using pointer           = char*;
    using reference         = char&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    Base64EncodeIterator()
        : iter(I{})
        , bits(0)
        , value(0)
    {}
    Base64EncodeIterator(I iter)
        : iter(iter)
        , bits(0)
        , value(0)
    {}
    enum Flags
    {
            EndFlag  = 0x8000,
            FillFlag = 0x4000,
            Data     = 0x3FFF,
    };

    bool operator==(Base64EncodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        if (iter == rhs.iter)
        {
            value = value | EndFlag;
        }
        return (iter == rhs.iter) && (bits == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(Base64EncodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    bool operator<(Base64EncodeIterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return iter < rhs.iter || (iter == rhs.iter && bits != 0);
    }
    char operator*()
    {
        bool fillFlag = value & FillFlag;
        if (bits < 6)
        {
            if (value & EndFlag)
            {
                value = EndFlag | FillFlag | ((value << 8) & Data);
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned char tmp = *iter++;
                value = ((value << 8) | tmp) &  Data;
            }
            bits += 8;
        }

        char result = '=';
        if (!fillFlag)
        {
            int tmp = (value >> (bits - 6)) & 0x3F;
            if (tmp < 26)
            {
                result = 'A' + tmp;
            }
            else if (tmp < 52)
            {
                result = 'a' + (tmp - 26);
            }
            else if (tmp < 62)
            {
                result = '0' + (tmp - 52);
            }
            else if (tmp == 62)
            {
                result = '+';
            }
            else
            {
                result = '/';
            }
        }

        bits -= 6;
        return result;
    }
    Base64EncodeIterator& operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    Base64EncodeIterator operator++(int)
    {
        Base64EncodeIterator  result(this);
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename I>
Base64DecodeIterator<I> make_decode64(I iter)
{
    return Base64DecodeIterator<I>(iter);
}
template<typename I>
Base64EncodeIterator<I> make_encode64(I iter)
{
    return Base64EncodeIterator<I>(iter);
}

}

#endif
```

Comment: where is the function `getBase64Message`?

Comment: @Peter It represents your code that retrieves a base 64 message from some part of your system. `std::string getBase64Message() {return "AAAA";}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid repeating yourself

I see a few cases where you can avoid repeating type names. For example:

```
I iter = I{};
```

This can be written as:

```
I iter{};
```

And:

```
Base64DecodeIterator operator++(int) {Base64DecodeIterator result(this); ++(*this); return result;}
```

Can be written as:

```
Base64DecodeIterator operator++(int) {auto result{*this}; ++(*this); return result;}
```

## Avoid writing multiple statements on one line

Since it is so customary in C and C++ to write one statement per line, when you combine multiple statements on one line, especially without whitespace between the statements, it can be confusing. Just split multi-statement one-liners into multiple lines, like:

```
Base64DecodeIterator operator++(int) {
    auto result{*this};
    ++(*this);
    return result;
}
```

## Consider supporting different input and output types

Consider a situation where you have a blob of binary data, to which you have a `char *` or `uint8_t *`, but you need to the base64-encoded string to use `wchar_t`. You could support this relatively easy by adding another template parameter to describe the output type, like so:

```
template<typename I, typename CharT = char>
class Base64EncodeIterator
{
     ...
     using value_type = CharT;
     using pointer = CharT*;
     using reference = CharT&;
     ...
     CharT operator*()
     {
         ...
     }
};
```

You would make the same change for `Base64DecodeIterator`. The `make_*` functions can look like:

```
template<typename CharT = char, typename I>
Base64DecodeIterator<I, CharT> make_encode64(I iter)
{
    return Base64EncodeIterator<I, CharT>(iter);
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> original(...);

std::wstring message(make_encode64<wchar_t>(std::begin(original)), 
                     make_encode64<wchar_t>(std::end(original)));

std::vector<uint8_t> recovered(make_decode64<uint8_t>(std::begin(message)),
                               make_decode64<uint8_t>(std::end(message)));
```

## Consider `I::value_type` not being an 8 bit integer type during encoding

Your code will accept the following:

```
std::vector<float> data{1.1, 42, 9.9e99};
make_encode64(data.begin());
```

But what this will do is cast each element of the vector to an `unsigned char` before encoding it. That is not what you would expect. Use SFINAE or Concepts to limit the allowed iterators to those that have a `value_type` that is an 8-bit integer type.

When encoding you have the same problem if you allow the output type to be specified as mentioned in the previous point.

## Making it work with ranges

The problem is that your classes do not implement a [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range). So you would need to introduce some class that provides both the begin and end iterator. But that could be as simple as:

```
template<typename I>
class Base64Decoder {
    Base64DecodeIterator begin_it;
    Base64DecodeIterator end_it;

public:
    Base64Decoder(const I &begin, const I &end): begin_it(begin), end_it(end) {}

    template<typename T>
    Base64Decoder(T &container): begin_it(std::begin(container)), end_it(std::end(container)) {}

    auto& begin() {
        return begin_it;
    }
 
    auto& end() {
        return end_it;
    }
};
```

And then you could write:

```
std::string input = "SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQo=";
Base64Decoder decoder(input);
for (auto c: input | std::ranges::views::take(5))
    std::cout << c;
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for the review. Not sure wide characters is a good idea as base64 is 1 octet encoding scheme.

Comment: Well on Windows it is common to use `wchar_t` to encode things like file names and so on, so there is some merit for it on some platforms. And it's templated, so it's just a few extra lines and no run-time overhead as far as I can tell.

Comment: So I understand what the result should look like. I decode the base64 to octet then I place 1 octet per wchar_t character or do I place multiple octets into a single character. When converting back do I treat each wchar_t as a single 8 bit value or multiple 8 bit values.